# ec2 not connecting on public IP after volume resize

Tags: amazon-ec2, oom

I am hosting two Wordpress sites on two different AWS EC2 micro instances running LAMP.

I have been getting OOM kills and decided to resize the instances to small.

Since increase the size of the instance I am only able to ssh into the instances but the public IP doesnt load.

[Site 1](http://ec2-52-210-2-56.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)

[Site 2](http://ec2-52-208-91-148.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you assign the public IP as elastic IP? If not, it gets a new one after restarting.

Comment: I didn't assign an EIP on either site. The public IP that I am trying to load is the new one assigned after the resize. I am able to ssh into the new instance at the new IP but not the public IP.

Comment: How is the security group of the instance configured?

Comment: all ports (80, 22, 443) SSH, HTTP, HTTPS are open at 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Hmm. When I nmap port 80, I get intermittend open/filtered. And when my `curl --head` finally does get through and sends headers, it stalls again. Do you have iptables on the machine? Does dmesg show anything? Other system logs?

Comment: I'm not using iptables unless it already comes with EC2. Im only using the luanch wizard security groups. dmesg shows an OOMKill at various processes. I'm not sure what to look for using dmesg? It seems that the old url is still registered even though I now have a new one. I'm not sure how to change this.